# Bug in tag editor suggestions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, edits

Hello,

I use Opera 9.64 on Linux.

When I edit tags (both retagging a question and tagging a brand new question (like this one)) the tag suggestion dropdown updates messes with focus of the text input field.

When new suggestions are displayed the cursor switches to the beginning of the text input field. If I type manually the rest of the tag that I want (rather than accepting one of the suggestions with a mouse click or whatever), I'll just prefix the first tag I've typed.

Comment: Same here. This used to work a couple of weeks ago and then went bonkers.

Comment: Manni: agreed, it used to work.

Comment: You are not alone: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14450/

Comment: random: yes, seems like a duplicate.

Comment: I just noted this on superuser.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may [need to upgrade to Opera 10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19254/adding-tags-to-a-new-question-in-opera-broken) in order for the autosuggest of tags to work on your machine.

Comment: what he said -- upgrade to Opera 10, the slightly less broken version. It is my hope by Opera 15, we'll have a version equivalent to the current state of IE, Firefox, or Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had to disable the autosuggest completely via user.js just so the form would submit. I'm using the latest version of Opera available at the time of this writing.

```
opera.defineMagicFunction(
    'bindTagFilterAutoComplete',
    function(){return false;}
);
```