# Adding tags to a new question in Opera broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, opera

In Opera 9.64 on Windows XP Pro, entry of tags for a new question is very difficult.

To reproduce:

Enter the first tag, select it in the AJAX popup.
Enter a second tag, select it in the AJAX popup.

Then, notice that sometimes the first tag has been replaced with the second tag.
Alterntively often the second tag has been inserted into the middle of the first tag.

For example, on this question I want to add the tags: opera tagging bug

Following the above approach I actually get:

bug tagging bug

This is very frustrating and makes sensible tagging almost impossible.  Please fix ASAP.

[UPDATE]

Upgrade to Opera 10.  Initial testing on StackOverflow and SuperUser indicate that entering tags now works correctly in Opera 10.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/tag-suggestion-only-works-for-the-first-tag/

Comment: This has been brought up before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/tag-suggestion-only-works-for-the-first-tag

Comment: I've seen that question.  Firstly it does not describe exactly the behaviour I'm getting and secondly it has not been resolved.  Bottom-line: The problem still exists and makes making tags very difficult.

Comment: Seeing some of Jeffs comments, it is important at least that he is aware that many users are using Opera and that it is not some "quirky" or obscure browser.  I use it for *all* of my browsing and it has no more problems than Firefox/Chrome/IE.

Comment: @ashh: I've used Opera too, and support it, and love it, but here, its a rather niche browser: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/browsers-and-screen-size-on-stack-overflow/ Opera has a wooping 2.44% of market share. I know they don't wanna just alienate Opera users, but they are not top in the priority list.

Answer (score 1):

Current workarounds:

Type the tags backwards.

Type in one and when you're done, hit <kbd>Home</kbd> or whatever your keyboard of choice does to get you back to the start of the input area. Then type a space and go back again to the front of the input.

Now type up the next tag and it will suggest it and prefill it properly. Return to the front and pad with that leading space for each tag you want to include.

Or type up the tags elsewhere and paste them in.

Comment: @random, thanks for the workaround.  I've been doing something similar (and wasting time and effort) for months.  I would actually like the problem to be fixed.

Comment: ok, then help us fix the JavaScript. It's specific to Opera (and IE) and has to do with getting the cursor position..

Comment: Forget about IE, it's Opera all the way down.

Comment: Jeff, will do.  Theres a new version of Opera (10.0) out recently I'll try with that too.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm sure someone's pointed you in this direction, but just in case: http://javascript.about.com/library/blmousepos.htm

Comment: text cursor in a textbox, not mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Opera 10.0 and it seems better at the tag editor. Try again.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it appears to work correctly for me too in Opera 10.  I've added an update to the question for other Opera users.  Must have been a bit quirky after all ;)  StackOverflow is the most useful thing on the internet, thanks for making it happen.